# If $O_i$ is open in $E_i$, is $O_1 \cup O_2$ open in $E_1 \cup E_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let's say that $E_1, E_2$ are nonempty closed sets in a T1 topological space $X$, and $O_i$ is an open set in $E_i$.  Is $O_1 \cup O_2$ necessarily open in $E_1 \cup E_2$?

I know this is false if $E_1, E_2$ are not closed.  For example, $O_1 =(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $O_2 =(2,3) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$ is open in the irrationals.  But $O_1 \cup O_2$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take $E_1=[0,1]$, $E_2=[1,3]$, $O_1=[0,1]$, and $O_2=(2,3)$.

Then $E_1\cup E_2=[0,3]$, and $O_1\cup O_2 =[0,1]\cup (2,3)$.

Now $[0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$, and $(2,3)$ is open in $[1,3]$, but $[0,1]\cup (2,3)$ is not open in $[0,3]$ because each neighborhood of $1$ meets the complement $(1,2]\cup \{3\}$.

*Comment.* The problem is that a set open in a subspace needn't be open in the larger space. It only needs to be the *intersection* of an open set in the larger space with the subspace.

Answer (score 1):

$E_1$ is open in $E_1$ and $\emptyset$ is open in $E_2$, independently of what $E_1$ and $E_2$ are. Is $E_1\cup\emptyset$ open in $E_1\cup E_2$?

Pick any space $E_2$ which contains a non-open subset $E_1$ for an example.